# Find the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [3+(-1)^{n}]^{n} z^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Find the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [3+(-1)^{n}]^{n} z^{n}$.

I recognize that the series is of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} z^{n}$. That is, a powers series.  Also I know that the radius of convergence is 1/4 but I do not know how to determine it. I have tried algebraic manipulations but I have not been able to get this radius.

Comment: Just use your [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) and compute $\limsup_n \sqrt[n]{(3+(-1)^n)^n}=\limsup_n (3+(-1)^n)=4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly by Cauchy-Hadamard Formula:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{[3+(-1)^n]^n}=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{4^n}=4$$

So $\;R=\cfrac14\;$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [3+(-1)^{n}]^{n} z^{n}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty(4z)^{2r}+\sum_{r=0}^\infty(2z)^{2r+1}$$

See use the [convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence) of Geometric Series or even more generic [Ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)